# Storing Files on the server in a non-public-accessible directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I can't seem to find information on how to do this. How can I use PHP to let a user upload a file on my website and then save that file on my server somewhere, but save it somewhere where noone can browse to its location? This will mainly be for PDF files, but they can also upload TXT or DOC/DOCX files, if that matters.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

it depends on what your web server setup is like.

If you are on a shared web host, some companies only have web accessible folders for each shared host client, others provide non-publicly accessible folders.  To check for this login through ftp and if you see either a `www` or `public-html` then anything that is not in that folder should not be accessible.

If you have a non-publicly accessible folder, good!

Learn to love `move_uploaded_file()`[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Just set the destination folder of the `move_uploaded_file` to a folder that isn't inside the web root and you're good.

If you do not have a non-publicly accessible folder, you need some `.htaccess` magic. (Here is a [starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632921/apache-htaccess-forbidding-direct-access-to-a-file-but-allow-rewrites-to-go).)

Comment: There's no www or public-html BUT it does let me browse outside of the /username folder BUT it brings an Access Is Denied error when I try to upload to it. I am using winhost.com for my site

Comment: that means the folder you have access to is publicly accessible, which means you need to be extra careful about storing data there.  Two things: 1.  use a non-word, hard to guess folder name (i.e.- `nU3y2vA/`) so that a hacker wouldn't be able to guess the name (security through obscurity) 2.  test, test, test any `.htaccess` rules you right and have your friends try to get through as well to make sure the rule is as airtight as possible